# Error creating a project using HSPI template

Tags: hspi

I followed "**Project templates for Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017**", but when I create a project using the template, I get following error:

> Package Installation Error
>
> The preinstalled packages have a reference to a missing Extension.
> Could not find an Extension with ID 'HomeSeerTemplates.Alex Dresko.82028f47-9623-4359-a6bf-244390c19608'.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, try uninstalling the extension and reinstall it. I apologize for the inconvenience, but you shouldn't have to do that again. I goofed a couple weeks ago and messed some things up. Let me know if the new version of the extension works.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thealexdresko.HomeSeerTemplates2